# Directly access/edit tvdb file of a TV Library (TV app) on Mac

Tags: tv.app

I'd like to change the date added field on a home movie in the TV app on macOS.  This will help organisation, to lay them out in correct chronological order.  This field cannot be updated in the app (via get info - the field value is displayed but is not editable).

Is there any practical way to do this?

I tried 'show package contents' of the TV library itself, but don't know what format the data is stored in or how to edit it (opening it in text edit doesn't show anything meaningful - the data is encoded in something that's not plain text).

Wondering if it's an SQLite database or something similar. (I tried opening the tvdb file inside the package with `sqlite3` but it says not a database).

Comment: Is the file *only* in the TV app or do you have the original? VLC (among others) will allow you to edit this metadata, then you could remove it from TV and re-import it.

Comment: I have the original. Thanks, I just tried that - Window/Media Information in VLC. I was able to edit a number of fields, which TV app also offers to edit, and these were propagated back to the info in tv app. However the field I'd like to edit isn't available there, (and is shown, but not editable, in get info in the TV app), it's "date added to library", seems stored in tvdb, not as metadata on the file.

Comment: "date added to library" sounds like something that Apple has decided is a fixed date, EG not-editable as that is specific to the tv.app and only records the date/time as indicated.

Comment: I don't think we have sufficient yet to conclude it's not possible. So for question to remain open, may be appropriate.